# how i send a class to another class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, selected

I'm trying to do Recyclerview multiple selection in Kotlin, I can do for one single adapter but I cant do for two or more adapters.

```
class MyItemDetailsLookup(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) :
ItemDetailsLookup<Long>() {
override fun getItemDetails(event: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<Long>? {
    val view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)
    if (view != null) {
        val selectedItems =  (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as ListaProdutosAdapter.MyViewHolder ) // here is my problem i need to make as "x adapter" i only can do for one adaper 
            .getItemDetails()


        return selectedItems
    }
    return null
}
```

}

I think the best solution is pass my adapter as a parameter, so I cant use multiples adapter in one function. if you have another solution pls tell me

Comment: Hey, you can create a List of Booleans in the adapter and, mark them as selected if you selected list item and create a method in adapter to fetch the ItemDetails<Long>? list based on the boolean array.

Comment: i just use this Boolean list to make my itens selected?